# Как нормально исключить из области обработки изображения некоторый массив Point (c#)?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, изображения, оптимизация

Доброго времени суток, господа!
Суть вопроса состоит в следующем:
Я обрабатываю фото попиксельно:

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(StartImage);
        Size size = bit.Size;
        for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = bit.GetPixel(x, y);
                ... Некоторые действия с пикселем ...
             }
```

Понадобилась возможность исключать из области обработки некоторые области. Ну, я подумал, что, мол, фигня вопрос: сейчас задам на вход массив точек, которые обрабатывать не нужно, а перед получением пикселя и его обработкой поставлю

```
if (ExceptPoints.Contains(new Point(x,y)))
```

и дело в шляпе! Но не тут-то было. Метод начал работать просто до чертиков медленно (а когда для тестирования я выбрал для исключения половину всего изображения, я не дождался результата и в течение 4 минут). Попробовал реализовать многопоточность для решения этой задачи. Но чуть не спалил себе ЦП (99% загрузки) хД
В общем, нужно как-то сие дело оптимизировать (или реализовать некорявую многопоточность), но в голову не идут идеи, как же это сделать.
Так что обращаюсь к вам за советом по сему нелегкому делу!

P.S. - исключаемые области изначально задаются кругами с рандомным радиусом. Но что проверять, входит ли точка в один из кругов, что проверять, есть ли она среди массива, содержащего все точки этих кругов, по времени выходит одно

Comment: Странно, проверка на вхождение в круг должна быть довольно быстрой. Попробуйте поместить точки в `HashSet<Point>`, в нём поиск должен быть практически мгновенный.

Comment: Если вам нужна _реально_ быстрая обработка, забудьте про медленный как улитка `GetPixel`, и используйте [`LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) (там внизу и пример есть).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо большое! Разобрался! Время обычной обработки изображения с 3 секунд упало до менее, чем десятой доли секунды! А благодаря Вашем совету с HashSet вне зависимости от количества элементов внутри него скорость обработки вообще никак не увеличивается!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Отлично! Тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два пути ускорения.

Во-первых, можно вместо линейной по количеству проверяемых точек проверке на вхождение в `List<Point>` (или `Point[]`) собрать точки в `HashSet<Point>`, у которого проверка на вхождение очень быстрая (O(1)).

Во-вторых, для работы с изображениями лучше всего отказаться от очень медленного `GetPixel`/`SetPixel`. Вместо этого имеет смысл получить «сырые» данные, используя [`LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) (в статье на MSDN есть хороший пример), и работать с ними.